# Function call at initialisation Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to set as part of a Google Chrome extension that it will perform an action as soon as the browser is opened.
It should record the time it performed this action and should only perform this action once each time the browser is opened.

I've looked into certain events but [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) would trigger too often and other events such as online might work but if the user disconnects and reconnects it would continue to trigger.

From my understanding I can have background JavaScript at the top level that will run when the extension is initialised, but I don't know how often this will trigger and what exactly causes this to trigger etc. I also tried [Chrome background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) but again, I'm not certain how often this may trigger.

I tried setting the function to trigger upon closing instead with window.onbeforeunload but this didn't work.

The intention is for this function to clear selected parts of the user's history upon closing (Or my solution upon opening) similar to Incognito and Mozilla Firefox's "Clear history on close". This may perform other actions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use a background page on which you use the following API https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup

Just listen for the event and run your code when it's triggered.

Comment: This probably seems obvious to you but I was reading through the JavaScript API and searching with everything and couldn't find this. I also spent much more time searching for a close trigger. Thank you very much.